# findElement that is generated HTML during runtime

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find an element that is generated from the PCA Predict API, found in this link here. http://www.pcapredict.com/en-gb/address-capture-software/

The code I have at the moment is as follows but it throws an timeout exception due to it not finding any elements. Yet the xpath is correct as I have checked it in developer tools.

```
    By PCA = By.id("inputPCAnywhere");
    driver.findElement(PCA).clear();
    driver.findElement(PCA).sendKeys(ValidPostcode);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='pcaitem pcafirstitem']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pcaitem pcafirstitem']")).click();
```

The element is visible on the page, and developer tools only returns one result that that xpath, there is no ID's to find it by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the first item is getting "selected" by default leading to it's class value being equal to the following:

```
<div class="pcaitem pcafirstitem pcaselected"...>...</div>
```

All other following results have only `pcaitem` class, but none have a `pcaitem pcafirstitem` class value.

In other words, your problem is the strict class match. I would improve the locator to have a partial match on the `class` attribute. For instance, with a *CSS selector*:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".pcaitem.pcafirstitem")));
```

Comment: Brilliant, such a simple fix as well. Much appreciated!